# IoT Edge on a smaller platform

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am currently working on a project which includes a gateway device that shall collect sensor data from other devices. This gateway uses IoT Edge and runs one custom module (written in C# .NET 5.0).

Initially we started development using Raspberry PI 4 and this worked well. Due to production costs and the quantity of gateways that need to be installed at some end customer premises we need to slim the platform down.

One platform that we are prototyping is a single-core ARM at 500MHz with 256MB LPDDR2 memory. On this platform we notice drastically slower start-up of both IoT Edge and our application.
Comparing timestamps from the IoT Edge service logs with application logs we have seen that starting the system takes between 6-8 minutes.
What we've observed so far (based on a test run I did just now):

- edgeAgent is started a couple of seconds after the IoT Edge service is started, at this point in time system CPU idle time decreases to zero and memory swapping increases,
- Several minutes after the IoT Edge service has started our module is started,
- Our module does `ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync()`, the CPU utilization of our module increases drastically. After 90+s connection to IoT Hub is retried with error `Communication_Error`.
- Almost three minutes later a ConnectionStatus.Connected is received by our application and it attempts to get the current twin state. This takes 30s (though we've often seen this fail).

Eventually the CPU usage on the system decreases to about 90% idle.

Total wall clock time from start of the IoT Edge service (09:52:13UTC) until our module is completely started (10:00:32UTC) is 8min 19s.
If I run our module outside of Docker and without IoT Edge it starts in 6s.

Is there anyway to decrease the time needed to start the system?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to work with IoT Edge on constrained devices. Take a look at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist?view=iotedge-2018-06#reduce-memory-space-used-by-iot-edge-hub) and try different timeToLiveSecs values, as well as "Reduce memory space used by IoT Edge hub".
I wrote an article with some findings I had in a similar setup https://www.hezser.de/blog/2020/11/03/azure-iot-edge-on-constraint-devices/

Comment: Thank you! We are currently not limited by storage but I disabled all protocols except AMQP, reduced storage time for messages and tweaked the Rocks DB parameter. The performance optimization on edgeHub were already disabled.

Although this resulted in a bit better performance we are still seeing 6+min startup times from boot which is still way off target.

Answer (score 0):

256MB memory is way too little for IoT Edge runtime. Empirically, at a minimum, a device with Raspberry Pi 3 level of resources is recommended. This means a minimum of 1GB RAM (2GB recommended).

Comment: Is this based on your experience or do you have a source on a study I can look at? Neither Google nor Azure are helpful in providing any answers on the requirements for running Azure IoT Edge. The closest I can find is https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/45 which says nothing.

AWS Greengrass (for reference) states clearly what the minimum requirements are: https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/faqs/